# Google search console shows the wrong Meta Title and Meta Description of my site

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-tags

This is my domain url  https://pearlresidencia.com.pk/ of my site. when i search my site name on google it show the wrong Meta Title and Meta Description. Here is the Screenshot's have a look at that.

[image]

This is the screenshot of my site Meta Title and Meta Description. Im using the plugin AIOSEO for SEO. The Meta Title of all other pages are fine only the issue im facing is in home page.

**Here is the screenshot after the issue
**

[image]

Trying to fix this meta title and description on google search

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to be seeing a different website. Check the HTML and screenshot from your home page in the Rich Result Tester via the VIEW TESTED PAGE:

https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result?id=s-S1qplPg-RyfEF-AFWpgg

If I crawl the page with a Googlebot UserAgent I get this alternate website.

That is called cloaking and indicates that your site has been hacked.

This article may help:

https://web.dev/how-do-i-know-if-my-site-was-hacked/